# Make div only as wide as sibling

Tags: html, css

I have an image within a parent div. I also want to have some text underneath the image within that parent div, but I only want the width of that text div to be as large as the image.

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        <div class="image-container">
            <img src="..." />
        </div>
        <div class="text">
        ...
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is a jsfiddle that illustrates my problem:
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8hV2E/)

How can I resolve this? I can't put the text inside the same div as the image because the image is cut off using a max-height css.

Comment: Is there a reason you only want to show the top of the image?

Comment: @MattWay I am planning on implementing a margin offset later on. I want to only show part of the image regardless, to not clutter my app.

Comment: Can't really understand what are you trying to do. Is it something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/8hV2E/4/

Comment: @Froient Yes, it's similar but I don't want the image to take up the full width of the container. Thats why I put an inline-block style to keep it sort of contained.

Comment: why not set a fixed width for your image and text ?

Comment: @shin I wanted to be able to allow for divs that are larger/smaller. If I set a fixed width, I lose some of that ability. e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/8hV2E/9/

Comment: @Kamran224 I've updated my answer, hope that helps :)

Comment: how about making `.child{position:relative}` and `.text{position:absolute;left:0px;right:0px;}`? Then .child div would be as wide as the image and .text would fit in the space. http://jsfiddle.net/8hV2E/12/

Comment: @gp this is perfect. If you can submit it as an answer I'll go ahead and mark it as solution for future references.

Comment: check my answer for the same.

Answer (score 1):

I simplified your markup and css a little bit. You can keep them in the same parent. use position absolute for the text and add position relative to its parent. that way it will take the parent's width. and the parent's width will be set by whatever size the image is, hence the text will be the same width as the image at the end of the day.

html:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="image-container">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/600/" />
        <div class="text">
            text   
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent {
    width: 700px;
}
.image-container {
    background: green;
    float:left;
    position: relative;
}

div.text {
    background: green;
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
    left:0;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Lah9/1/)

Comment: I think they want the text below the image, but keeping the same width as the image.

Comment: they have display:inline-block for image-container, so I assumed he wants it side by side.

Comment: Yeah fair enough. Question needs to be more specific I think.

Comment: Sorry, updated the description. I want it underneath.

Comment: modified my answer. width:50% still works, but needs to be used with combination of display:inline-block for both elements.

Comment: I tried the 50% solution initially but it also resizes the image. I was trying to find a solution without that side affect.

Comment: @Sammy What do you mean? I have full control of the HTML and the text.

Comment: the only reason I asked because the markup could be more simplified, I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you were after? Can you use jquery?

```
$('.child').width($('.image-container').width());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YRYZA/

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
.child{ position: relative; }
.text{ position: absolute; left: 0px; right: 0px; }
```

Then .child div would be as wide as the image (not influenced by .text width) and .text would fit in the space.

JSFiddle: jsfiddle.net/8hV2E/12